# Auto Forward Emails from Client in outlook to external email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

HI all,

autoforwarding at exchange level is disabled by the server admin, so i have got some VBA code that forwards emails to an external email(my blackberry email). I have it working fine, but was wondering is there any way when recieving the email on my other account that instead of seeing all the emails from me, you can see the original sender in the from part?

here is my code

```
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim strMsg As String
Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem

Set myFwd = Item.Forward

myFwd.Recipients.Add "asb@x.net"
myFwd.Subject = Mid(myFwd.Subject, 4)
myFwd.Save


myFwd.Send
Set myFwd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not a user of Outlook, this old article suggests a way:
[OL2000: How to Programmatically Set a Form's From Field](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232309).

Perhaps this could work :

```
myFwd.SentOnBehalfOfName = Item.SentOnBehalfOfName
```

I also noticed in the article [MailItem Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210946%28v=office.11%29.aspx) the property of `SenderName`, which may also be useful.